How to replace (***) with \(***\) with sed
so I wanted to write a script to replace special characters with their escaped equivalent so I can pass it to mkdir command.
As a friend used a similar line I can use this to replace parantheses with underline like below:
echo 'Hello (World)' | sed 's/(\|)/_/g'

but when I changed it to below command the output is not what I desire
echo 'Hello (World)' | sed 's/(\|)/\(\|\)/g'

system output:      Hello (|)World(|)
my desired output:  Hello \(World\)
any way to do this? I used other people's suggestions like using "tr" command but couldn't get the desired output from that either.

If the name of the directory is supposed to be Hello (World), then why no just mkdir 'Hello (World)'? Or, if you will, dirname='Hello (World)'; mkdir "$dirname"?  If you're using the variable unquoted, then no manner of escaping the parentheses will help you.

I suggest:
1. somewhat readable version
echo 'Hello (World)' | sed 's/(/\\(/g' | sed 's/)/\\)/g'

Each invocation targets one kind of parenthesis. The "find" part simply looks for the parenthesis, and the replace part puts the same parenthesis back, but after a backslash, which we need to escape.
2. Compact version
This will work too:
echo 'Hello (World)' | sed -E 's/(\(|\))/\\\1/g'

Here we call sed only once.
The -E tells sed to behave differently (and more "modernly") when it comes to parentheses and special characters, using the extended regular expressions. This allows us to use capture groups.
In the "find" part, we tell sed to look for opening or closing parenthesis. They are escaped. The entire "( or )" group is itself enclosed in parentheses, which are not escaped as they are used to tell sed to memorise what's found in that group. Then in the replace part, we put the backslash (escaped as before), and whatever was found by sed earlier, referred to as \1.
3. linking this to mkdir
The core of the question was around achieving the provided output via sed. As to the original intent briefly mentioned by the OP, that approach is a bit contrived, but can work. For a directory named "Hello (World)" this would work:
echo 'Hello (World)' | sed 's/(/\\(/g' | sed 's/)/\\)/g' | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs mkdir

We need to also escape the space, in the same way as before. Xargs is used to pass the output of the previous command to mkdir.
Alternatively:
echo 'Hello (World)' | sed 's/(/\\(/g' | sed 's/)/\\)/g' | xargs -I{} mkdir '{}'

This saves us the escaping of the spaces by enclosing the previous output between quotes (better not have quotes in the desired name!)
As mentioned this is quite contrived, and the other answer about using mkdir while simply enclosing the names in quotes is likely the way to go for the OP.

Using -E here only makes things harder. Since parentheses are not special in BRE but are special in ERE, activating ERE just makes your life more difficult for no reason. Even with the approach you use here, without the -E things are much simpler: sed 's/(/\\(/g' and sed 's/)/\\)/g'.

Could you also show how to "pass this to the mkdir command" (which is what the user wants to do)?

@terdon Indeed, I'm less familiar with sed "without -E", as I mentioned. But you're right, in the first approach it's more readable without it. I'll amend my reply.
I suppose -E is still needed in order to make the 2nd approach work since we need the group capture to work.

@Kusalananda I'll add a note about this, though I considered the "desired output" to be the core of the question.

@Pierric it isn't needed for the second approach either, but it doesn't make things that much more complicated there since with ERE you need to escape the parentheses so they are not capture groups, but with BRE you need to escape them so they can be capture groups, and also escape the | for it to be an OR, so you only need one more \  than you do with -E: echo 'Hello (World)' | sed 's/\((\|)\)/\\\1/g'. That said, it is much easier to use & and a character class instead: echo 'Hello (World)' | sed 's/[()]/\\&/g'.

What is the difference between your final long pipeline and echo 'Hello (World)' | xargs -I{} mkdir '{}', or, in fact, mkdir 'Hello (World)'?

@terdon I didn't know about & myself, thanks for bringing that up. You should write a new answer, it would then be the best answer (in my opinion) on the question actually asked.

@Kusalananda not much, it's a contrived way to get there. Since the OP was asking about using sed to then passing the output to mkdir, this is how one could go about it. But as already clarified, for his actual intent (and not his question) the other answer about using mkdir is the relevant one. I included this only to bridge things together. I guess this could be relevant if they wanted to do more character replacement than just escaping parentheses.


… with their escaped equivalent so I can pass it to mkdir command.

Don't do that at all. Instead, quote the string:
name1="Hello (World)!"
name2="I want this to be a five-star directory (*****)"
mkdir -- "${name1}" "${name2}"

or just
mkdir "Hello (World)"
mkdir "I want this to be a five-star directory (*****)"

simply works.
